# Open3d: Visualize PLY file with face colors

Tags: python, colors, mesh, open3d, ply-file-format

Is there a way of reading a PLY file and show the face colors when visualizing the geometry?
This is how I open a dialog window to select the PLY file and read the mesh and subsequently visualize it.

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    input_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('PLY Files', '*.ply')])
    file_name = os.path.basename(input_file)
    self.mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(input_file)

    self.mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([self.mesh])
```

This excerpt is from a method of a larger app, when I click a button, the dialog opens up, and when the file is selected the visualization window is opened, that is why it has the "self."